# Does Oracle index rebuilding after bulk delete operation - improves performance of select query

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing, oracle19c

I have 3 transactions tables in oracle , volume details are as below

```
table_1 --> it adds 3M trans daily
table_2 --> it adds 4M trans daily
table_3 --> it adds 2M trans daily
```

I have created a stored procedure and scheduled it to run on Sunday( non business hours)
SO my data purge process , deletes below volume ( older than 6 months - which is not needed)

```
   purge table_1 --> it deletes 15M to 20M trans on sunday
   purge  table_2 --> it deletes 20M to 24M trans on sunday
   purge  table_3 --> it deletes 10M to 13M trans on sunday
```

After this I have added - logic to online rebuild the index related to these tables
my table name variable is --> tab_name

```
 FOR IND IN (select ui.index_name from user_indexes ui where ui.TABLE_NAME = tab_name  ) LOOP


                v_ind:=IND.INDEX_NAME;
                v_sql_ind := 'ALTER INDEX MY_SCHEMA.' || v_ind || ' REBUILD ONLINE TABLESPACE MY_TABLE_SPACE NOLOGGING' ;
                
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_ind;

            END LOOP;
```

This is saving space for us - on DB ( my primary goal is achieved)
How ever - from application layer - we are not able to identify if it is improving performance

so i need help in understanding

- is rebuilding index is needed after such bulk delete operation
- Does it really improve performance
- Is there any other way - apart from rebuilding index

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Usage of *partitioned* tables and *local* indexes would be probably the right solution. Otherwise check the excellent discussion  of Jonathan Lewis [here](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/index-rebuild/) and [here](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2017/08/03/rebuilding-indexes/). You need to *rebuild* basically if the index has free space *that can't be reused*, i.e. if the index would gets smaller when rebuild *before* the delete. Wheter the rebuild has an effect on the queries you can observe in the index metadata, e.g. if the index blevel decrease (which is rarely the case)

Comment: _"we are not able to identify if it is improving performance"_   If you can't identify a performance improvement, isn't it then self-evident that there is no performance improvement in your situation?

Comment: thank you for your comments , initially it didn't show up performance betterment - but after few runs - we are seeing the better performance

Answer (score 0):

one thing we added as - index check - if the rebuild is required

We can run below queries and it will help you identify

```
-- this runs analysis on the oracle index
ANALYZE INDEX MY_INDEX VALIDATE STRUCTURE;

-- this will fetch the height if index - it is adviced if the height is >= 4 - then it is better to rebuild index
SELECT name, height,lf_rows,lf_blks,del_lf_rows FROM INDEX_STATS;
```